# node-xmpp-client cannot connect to node-xmpp-server from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmp, node-xmpp

I'm trying to connect to node-xmpp-server from node-xmpp-client browser.But I have the following errors:

[image]

---

[image]

Thanks for any help!